# I need solution for a CS50 pset1 assignment problem (Mario More) in C

Tags: c, cs50

I have been dealing with the "Mario more" assignment in CS50. The following code gives accurate results and satisfies all the conditions enlisted in the problem set. However, the code when evaluated by check50, shows many fundamental errors.

I have attached my code, my terminal window output (link) and check50 output (link) below. Please help me to understand what is it that I am doing wrong. As the terminal window output and desired output is exactly same, why does check50 differ? Any and all suggestions are welcome!

Thanking you,

Pritish

**Code as follows:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

void print_space(int n);
void print_hashtag(int n);


int main(void)
{
    int height, space, hashtag;
    do
    {
        height = get_int("What's the height of pyramid from 1 to 8?\n");
    }
    while(height < 1 || height > 8);

    space = height-1;
    hashtag=1;

    for(int i=0;i<height;i++)
    {
        print_space(space);
        print_hashtag(hashtag);
        printf("  ");
        print_hashtag(hashtag);
        printf("\n");
        space--;
        hashtag++;
    }
}




void print_space(int n)
{
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf(" ");
    }
}

void print_hashtag(int n)
{
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("#");
    }
}
```

**Terminal Window Output as follows:**

[image: Terminal window output]

**Check50 output as follows:**

[image: Check50 output]

Comment: The terminal is running `mario2` while Check50 is running `mario`. Are you sure you are submitting latest correct file?

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the obvious mistake. As a beginner, I will surely learn to check all basic things.